# Как передать полный список по указателю в функцию из DLL, Python?

Tags: python, dll, ctypes

Как передать полный список по указателю в функцию из DLL, Python?

Код работает, но функция wFpsCameraCreate принимает только первое значение KeyMatr[1], а второе из списка не видит.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно передать массив в функцию.

```
from ctypes import *

# give location of dll
ws3d = cdll.LoadLibrary("..//WS3DCoreLib.dll")

class wKeyCode(Enum):
    wKC_UP = 0x26
    wKC_KEY_W = 0x57

class wKeyAction(Enum):
    wKA_MOVE_FORWARD = 0
    wKA_MOVE_BACKWARD = 1
    wKA_STRAFE_LEFT = 2
    wKA_STRAFE_RIGHT = 3
    wKA_JUMP_UP = 4
    wKA_COUNT = 5
    wKA_FORCE_32BIT = 0x7fffffff

class wKeyMap(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
    ("Action", c_uint32),
    ("KeyCode", c_uint32)
    ]
<pre>
class wNode(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("wNode", POINTER(c_uint32))]

def wFpsCameraCreate(rotateSpeed = 100, moveSpeed = 0.1, keyMapArray = 0, keyMapSize = 0, noVerticalMovement = False, jumpSpeed = 0):
    ws3d.wFpsCameraCreate.restype = wNode
    return ws3d.wFpsCameraCreate(c_float(rotateSpeed), c_float(moveSpeed), keyMapArray, keyMapSize, noVerticalMovement, c_float(jumpSpeed))

def wKeyMapDefault(i):
    s = []
    s.append(wKeyMap()); s.append(wKeyMap())
    s[1].Action = wKeyAction.wKA_MOVE_FORWARD.value
    s[1].KeyCode = wKeyCode.wKC_KEY_W.value
    s.append(wKeyMap())
    s[2].Action = wKeyAction.wKA_MOVE_FORWARD.value
    s[2].KeyCode = wKeyCode.wKC_UP.value
    return s

# Create FPS-camera
KeyMatr = []; KeyMatr = wKeyMapDefault(1)
CameraNode = wFpsCameraCreate(100, 0.1, 
pointer(KeyMatr[1]), 8, False, 0)
```

Буду признателен.

Comment: Мой ответ на предыдущий ваш вопрос не помог?

Comment: Да, огромное спасибо, заработало, сейчас вот со списками в функцию вожусь.

Comment: Тогда стоит [отметить его решением](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Ага, отметил, спасибо.

Comment: wFpsCameraCreate должна принимать массив чего? Каких типов?

Comment: Должна принимать третьем параметром массив из wKeyMap(), но видит только первый элемент списка.

Answer (score 0):

Проверить мне не на чем, но должно быть как-то так

```
ws3d.wFpsCameraCreate.argtypes = [..., POINTER(wKeyMap), ...]
ws3d.wFpsCameraCreate(..., byref(KeyMatr), ...)
```